# Capturing ExactTarget landing page in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

So I decided to build a survey instead of use a landing page.
The survey is embedded within an email.
So I now need to update Salesforce based on the selection of the survey questions. Where do I need to write my script which performs that?

==================================================================

Original Question

I have a form on my ExactTarget landing page.
I want to capture the user entered data and send it to Salesforce CRM.

a) I'm not sure if any integration I'll do (APMscript or Javascript HTTP) will work with a PE salesforce org which does not have API enabled.
b) There some documentation on how to use Javascript in a landing page and/or AMPScript in emails but they don't show where these scripts go and how to get to the right page to add them

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Dedo, this is a bit open ended at the moment. When posting here it's good practice to show what research you've done and where you're stuck. Do you have a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: a) I'm not sure if any integration I'll do (APMscript or Javascript HTTP) will work with a PE salesforce org which does not have API enabled. b) There some documentation on how to use Javascript in a landing page and/or AMPScript in emails but they don't show where these scripts go and how to get to the right page to add them

Answer (score 3):

This is what SmartCapture is for. Quoting the official documentation

> Smart Capture is a tool you can use to create lead capture forms to
>   include in your landing pages. When a lead completes the form on the
>   landing page and clicks the Submit button, the Smart Capture form
>   automatically adds the information to the subscriber list, data
>   extension, or outside data source such as an integrated CRM system.

[image]

You can find more details on SmartCapture and how to integrate with Salesforce [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/smart_capture/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also explore using AMPScript Functions to Create, Update, Retrieve, or Send to Salesforce Objects.  You can use these functions on a SFMC Landing Page and it'll allow you to pass this back to your Salesforce Instance when they submit the form.  This would be an option if you're not using Smart Capture forms.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/

Comment: I read this but I'm not sure where I get started, how do I get to the page where I put these scripts

Comment: These functions will go on the same Landing Page (SFMC) that contains your form.  You would set everything up on the landing page and pass this upon form submit.